# Regex how prevent string containing only the "?" character

Tags: regex

I'm searching for a Regex to avoid letting user to enter a string with only a single ? character.
Here are examples of what I want to achieve:
?        Not Ok (I want to avoid letting this)
?a      Ok
a?      Ok
??      Ok
???     Ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches either any one- character string which is different from `?` or any string with at least two characters

```
^([^?]|..+)$
```